# How to get the latest set of data available out of a MySQL table (data sets are stored daily)?

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a MySQL table with following setup:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `coords` (
  `project_id` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `day` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `x` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `y` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `z` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tid`,`day`,`x`,`y`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Each project is running several days. Each day some cases are tested and the results (set of coordinates) are saved in this table (along with project id and day number). The same set of x and y coordinates can be saved more often than once (the z coordinate is the actual result).

Now I want to get all available sets of coordinates for a single project with the latest data available.

I.e., assuming I have following data:

```
pid | day | x | y | z
  1 |   1 | 2 | 1 | 5
  1 |   1 | 2 | 2 | 6
  1 |   2 | 3 | 3 | 7
  1 |   3 | 2 | 1 | 8
  1 |   3 | 3 | 3 | 9
```

The query shall now return:

```
day | x | y | z
  1 | 2 | 2 | 6
  3 | 2 | 1 | 8
  3 | 3 | 3 | 9
```

I was trying following query:

```
SELECT day, x, y, z 
FROM coords 
WHERE pid = 1 
GROUP BY CONCAT(tid,'.',x,'.',y) 
ORDER BY day DESC
```

But this query returns old data, just as day = 1, x|y|z = 2|1|5 instead of day = 3 and x|y|z = 2|1|8.

Could someone please point me in the right direction of what I am missing here?

Thanks in advance,
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out :).

```
SELECT
  day,
  x,
  y,
  z 
FROM
  coords
    JOIN
  (SELECT MAX(tid) AS max_tid FROM coords GROUP BY CONCAT_WS('.', day, x, y)) sub ON (sub.max_tid = coords.tid)
WHERE
  pid = 1
```

Comment: I had to exchange some vars, but I got it to work with following query:

SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(a.pid,'.',a.x,'.',a.y), a.day, a.x, a.y, a.z, a.nvt, a.tag, a.building FROM coords a JOIN (SELECT MAX(day) AS max_day FROM coords GROUP BY CONCAT('.', pid,'.', x,'.', y)) sub ON (sub.max_day =  a.day) WHERE a.pid = 1

I'll do some performance tests on this one, if it's going to be too slow I'll go for exus' solution though.

Comment: @Paul: it will be slow with a lot of data that's a fact. If you want to make it fast(er) denormalize the DB and pre-count the concatenation for each row.

Answer (score 1):

well i thing you have a problem there because once you do `Select * from coords order by day asc limit 1` you will get randomly. 2.1.5 or 2.2.6. depending on how the database feels it. You definitly need more specific "dayting" or ID or something according to what will the database know in what order those lines were inserted in. Add an id field there for example.

```
Select distinct day, x,y,z 
FROM coords
where pid = 1
order by id desc
```

This might do the magic if you add the id field in there

Comment: But the day is some kind of id (not unique though), isn't? The same set of x,y coordinates are only ever submitted once a day. So by ordering by day desc and an additional grouping by day I thought this should do the magic.

Comment: But the database will still have issues knowing which line was inserted last. the order by does not make sense in this case. If you don't want to do too much complicated query you should consider adding that id field.

Comment: I got it to work by altering Kaltas query. It shall do it for now, since I have a couple of hundreds of thousands rows already and don't want to alter the database scheme. But if it's too slow, I'll give the id column a try.